# How to use AnchorAnimation within an SequentialAnimation?

Tags: animation, qml

I want to move a widget to the center of the container in a sequential animation, but it does not work:

```
SequentialAnimation {
    PauseAnimation { duration: 1000 }
    AnchorAnimation {
        duration: 1000
        //  ERROR: Cannot assign to non-existent default property 
        AnchorChanges {
            target: widget1
            anchors.horizontalCenter: container.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
....
```

Neither:

```
SequentialAnimation {
    PauseAnimation { duration: 1000 }
    // ERROR: Cannot assign object to list
    AnchorChanges {
        target: widget1
        anchors.horizontalCenter: container.horizontalCenter
    }
    AnchorAnimation {
        duration: 1000
    }
....
```

Comment: Where is located your SequentialAnimation in your QML file (i.e. what is its parent?). Can you provide a  bit more code with surrounding items?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `AnchorChanges` item into an animation. You have put it into a state definition.

Refer to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-anchoranimation.html) for more details.